# Spreadsheet with reverse Polish equation solving

Tags: java, object-oriented

Interested to hear any suggestions on object orientation and style for this simple spreadsheet implementation. The spreadsheet contains cells with equations in reverse polish notation and has a solver method to either determine the cell values or throw an exception if a circular reference exists.

```
/**
 * This class encapsulates a spreadsheet which is a collection of cells together
 * with methods for solving the spreadsheet.
 */
public class SpreadSheet {

    private int nRows; // number of rows in the spreadsheet
    private int nCols; // number of columns, must be less than or equal to 26
    private ArrayList<Cell> cells; // the cells within the spreadsheet in row by row
                            // order

    /**
     * Construct a spreadsheet from a given expression array.
     *
     * @param nRows
     *            number of rows in spreadsheet.
     * @param nCols
     *            number of columns in spreadsheet.
     * @param exprArray
     *            an array of Strings containing the expressions for the cells
     *            of the spreadsheet specified in row by row order.
     */
    public SpreadSheet(int nRows, int nCols, String... exprArray) {
        this.nRows = nRows;
        this.nCols = nCols;
        cells = new ArrayList<Cell>(exprArray.length);
        for (String expressionString : exprArray) {
            cells.add(new Cell(this, expressionString));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Solve a spreadsheet and return the solution of each cell.
     *
     * @return array of doubles containing the solution to each cell in row by
     *         row order.
     * @throws CircularReferenceException if spreadsheet contains a circular reference.
     */
    public Double[] dump() throws CircularReferenceException {
        int validCells = 0; // cells with valid values
        int validCellsPreviousIteration = 0; // cells with valid values in the
                                                // previous iteration
        try {
            while (validCells < cells.size()) {
                evaluate(); // evaluate each cell in the spreadsheet
                validCells = countValidCells();
                if (validCells == validCellsPreviousIteration) {
                    throw new CircularReferenceException(); // throw exception
                                                            // if number of
                                                            // cells that have
                                                            // valid values
                                                            // has not increased
                } else {
                    validCellsPreviousIteration = validCells;
                }
            }
        } catch (InvalidOperatorException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        try {
            return getValues();
        } catch (InvalidValueException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve cell from particular row and column of spreadsheet. Indexing is
     * 0 based.
     *
     * @param row
     *            row of cell.
     * @param column
     *            column of cell.
     * @return cell at location (row,column).
     */
    public Cell getCell(int row, int column) {
        return cells.get(row * nCols + column);
    }

    /**
     * Construct an array containing the value of each cell in the spreadsheet
     * in row by row order.
     *
     * @return array of doubles containing values.
     * @throws InvalidValueException
     */
    private Double[] getValues() throws InvalidValueException {
        Double[] values = new Double[cells.size()];
        int i = 0;
        for (Cell cell : cells) {
            values[i++] = cell.getValue();
        }
        return values;
    }

    /**
     * Count number of cells within the spreadsheet with valid values.
     *
     * @return number of cells with valid values.
     */
    private int countValidCells() {
        int validCells = 0;
        for (Cell cell : cells) {
            if (cell.isValueValid()) {
                validCells++;
            }
        }
        return validCells;
    }

    /**
     * Evaluate the expression of every cell within the spreadsheet.
     *
     * @throws InvalidOperatorException
     */
    private void evaluate() throws InvalidOperatorException {
        for (Cell cell : cells) {
            cell.evaluate();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Exception for when spreadsheet contains a circular reference.
     */
    public class CircularReferenceException extends RuntimeException {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    }
}
```

Here is the `Cell` class:

```
/**
 * This class encapsulates a single cell within a spreadsheet.
 */
public class Cell {

    private SpreadSheet spreadsheet; // spreadsheet to which cell belongs,
                                        // necessary for resolving cell
                                        // references
    private String expression; // expression within cell in reverse Polish
                                // notation
    private double value; // numerical value of evaluating expression
    private boolean valueValid; // whether a valid value has been found so
                                // far. This will change from false to true
                                // once all cell references have been
                                // resolved, provided that there are no
                                // circular references

    /**
     * Constructor for a cell belonging to a particular spreadsheet.
     *
     * @param spreadsheet
     *            SpreadSheet to which Cell belongs.
     * @param expression
     *            expression within cell.
     */
    public Cell(SpreadSheet spreadsheet, String expression) {
        this.spreadsheet = spreadsheet;
        this.expression = expression;
    }

    /**
     * Evaluates expression within a cell. Expression must be in reverse Polish
     * notation.
     *
     * @throws InvalidOperatorException
     *             if cell expression contains an invalid operator.
     */
    public void evaluate() throws InvalidOperatorException {
        if (!valueValid) { // prevent reevaluation of cells that have valid
                            // values
            try {
                // create stack containing terms in expression
                Deque<String> expressionStack = new ArrayDeque<String>(
                        Arrays.asList(expression.split("\\s")));
                value = evaluateRpn(expressionStack);
                valueValid = true;
            } catch (UnresolvedReferenceException e) {
                // no action is necessary if a reference is unresolved, since it
                // may be resolved at a later iteration during the solution of
                // the spreadsheet
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get value of a cell. This is the numerical value resulting from
     * evaluating the cell's expression.
     *
     * @return numerical value resulting from evaluating cell's expression.
     * @throws InvalidValueException
     *             if a valid value is not currently available.
     */
    public double getValue() throws InvalidValueException {
        if (isValueValid()) {
            return value;
        } else {
            throw new InvalidValueException();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Check if a valid numerical value has been evaluated for the cell. This
     * will be true when evaluate() is called on the cell and all of the cell
     * references in the cell's expression can be resolved.
     *
     * @return whether cell value is valid.
     */
    public boolean isValueValid() {
        return valueValid;
    }

    /**
     * Evaluate an expression contained within an ExpressionStack.
     *
     * @param expressionStack
     *            an expression represented as a stack of individual terms.
     * @return evaluation of expression
     * @throws InvalidOperatorException
     * @throws UnresolvedReferenceException
     */
    private double evaluateRpn(Deque<String> expressionStack)
            throws InvalidOperatorException, UnresolvedReferenceException {
        String term = expressionStack.removeLast();
        if (isCellReference(term)) {
            // if last term in expression is a cell reference then resolve it
            return resolveCellReference(term);
        } else {
            double x, y;
            try {
                // if last term in expression is double then return it
                x = Double.parseDouble(term);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                // otherwise last term is an operator, evaluate operands and
                // apply operator
                y = evaluateRpn(expressionStack);
                x = evaluateRpn(expressionStack);
                x = applyOperator(x, y, term);
            }
            return x;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Apply operator to operands x and y.
     *
     * @param x
     *            first operand.
     * @param y
     *            second operand.
     * @param operator
     * @return result of operation
     * @throws InvalidOperatorException
     */
    private double applyOperator(double x, double y, String operator)
            throws InvalidOperatorException {
        if (operator.equals("+"))
            return x + y;
        else if (operator.equals("-"))
            return x - y;
        else if (operator.equals("*"))
            return x *= y;
        else if (operator.equals("/"))
            return x / y;
        else
            throw new InvalidOperatorException(operator);
    }

    /**
     * Resolve a reference to another cell within the spreadsheet. If the other
     * cell has a valid value, then the value will be returned, otherwise an
     * UnresolvedReferenceException will be thrown.
     *
     * @param reference
     *            reference to another cell in the spreadsheet.
     * @return value of referenced cell.
     * @throws UnresolvedReferenceException
     */
    private double resolveCellReference(String reference)
            throws UnresolvedReferenceException {
        int col = reference.charAt(0) - 'A';
        int row = Integer.parseInt(reference.substring(1)) - 1;
        Cell referencedCell = spreadsheet.getCell(row, col);
        try {
            return referencedCell.getValue();
        } catch (InvalidValueException e) {
            throw new UnresolvedReferenceException();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether a term in an expression is a reference to another cell.
     *
     * @param term
     * @return whether term is a cell reference.
     */
    private boolean isCellReference(String term) {
        return Character.isLetter(term.charAt(0));
    }

    /**
     * Thrown to indicate than an invalid operator is specified in cell
     * expression.
     */
    public class InvalidOperatorException extends Exception {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private String operator;

        public InvalidOperatorException(String operator) {
            this.operator = operator;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return "Invalid operator " + operator;
        }

    }

    /**
     * Thrown to indicate that a cell reference cannot be resolved. This occurs
     * if a valid value is not currently available for the referenced cell.
     */
    public class UnresolvedReferenceException extends Exception {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    }

    /**
     * Thrown to indicate that getValue() was called on a cell with a value that
     * is currently invalid.
     */
    public class InvalidValueException extends Exception {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. ```
   private String expression; // expression within cell in reverse Polish
                               // notation
   private double value; // numerical value of evaluating expression
   ```

   I'd rename it to `rpnExpression` and `evaluatedValue` which will make the comments unnecessary. (Check *Clean Code* by Robert C. Martin, page 53-54 also.)
2. ```
   public Cell(SpreadSheet spreadsheet, String expression) {
       this.spreadsheet = spreadsheet;
       this.expression = expression;
   }
   ```

   I'd check `null`s here. [checkNotNull from Guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Preconditions.html) is a gread choice for that.
   (*Effective Java, 2nd edition, Item 38: Check parameters for validity*)
3. ```
   if (!valueValid) { // prevent reevaluation of cells that have valid
                       // values
   ```

   This condition is a good candidate for guard clause.
   References: *Replace Nested Conditional with Guard Clauses* in *Refactoring: Improving the Design of Existing Code*; [Flattening Arrow Code](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/01/flattening-arrow-code.html)
4. ```
   throw new InvalidValueException();
   ```

   I'd put into the message the invalid expression.
5. ```
    * @throws InvalidOperatorException
    * @throws UnresolvedReferenceException
   ```

   Are these lines necessary?
6. ```
   if (isCellReference(term)) {
       // if last term in expression is a cell reference then resolve it
       return resolveCellReference(term);
   } else {
       double x, y;
       try {
           // if last term in expression is double then return it
           x = Double.parseDouble(term);
       } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
           // otherwise last term is an operator, evaluate operands and
           // apply operator
           y = evaluateRpn(expressionStack);
           x = evaluateRpn(expressionStack);
           x = applyOperator(x, y, term);
       }
       return x;
   }
   ```

   The `isCellReference` is a guard clause, so the `else` keyword and its parentheses are unnecessary:

   ```
   if (isCellReference(term)) {
       // if last term in expression is a cell reference then resolve it
       return resolveCellReference(term);
   }
   double x, y;
   try {
       // if last term in expression is double then return it
       x = Double.parseDouble(term);
   } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
       // otherwise last term is an operator, evaluate operands and
       // apply operator
       y = evaluateRpn(expressionStack);
       x = evaluateRpn(expressionStack);
       x = applyOperator(x, y, term);
   }
   return x;
   ```
7. Furthermore, I'd minimize the scope of the local variables:

   ```
   try {
       return Double.parseDouble(term);
   } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
       // otherwise last term is an operator, evaluate operands and
       // apply operator
       double y = evaluateRpn(expressionStack);
       double x = evaluateRpn(expressionStack);
       return applyOperator(x, y, term);
   }
   return x;
   ```

   (*Effective Java, 2nd edition, Item 45: Minimize the scope of local variables*)
8. ```
   if (operator.equals("+"))
   ```

   I prefer to invert the equals here:

   ```
   if ("+".equals(operator))
   ```

   It protects from `NullPointerException`s when the `operator` parameter is `null`.
9. ```
   } catch (InvalidValueException e) {
       throw new UnresolvedReferenceException();
   }
   ```

   Usually it's a good practice to pass the cause to constructor of the new exception:

   ```
   throw new UnresolvedReferenceException(e);
   ```
10. ```
    public InvalidOperatorException(String operator) {
        this.operator = operator;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Invalid operator " + operator;
    }
    ```

    I'd pass the `"Invalid operator " + operator` string to the constructor of the superclass (as the message) and omit the `operator` field:

    ```
    public InvalidOperatorException(String operator) {
        super("Invalid operator " + operator);
    }
    ```

    It's more common, and logging libraries will print the class name too, not just the string, which helps debugging.

Answer (score 3):

I did not go in great detail, but it looks pretty good.

Just be careful with method names: `dump()` and `evaluateRpn()`. Usually abbreviations are avoided in Java.

I don't know if you should have made cells a two-dimensional `List` of `List` instead. It's a bit cleaner, but it's annoying when you want to loop over all cells. I guess you thought about it before deciding on a single array. Another option would be to define some `Grid` class that stores a `List` of `List` and that implements `Iterable`.

I would probably try to get the spreadsheet reference out of `Cell`. The evaluate methods would then need to be moved to `SpreadSheet`.  I'm not sure that I really prefer that to the current implementation.

Another suggestion would be to use an `Enum` for the 4 operations.  Yet again, I'm not sure it's a good idea, but you could look into it.

Comment: Thanks! Actually dump() was the name required for external reasons, I don't particularly like it myself. Regarding evaluateRpn() do you think evaluateReversePolishNotation() would be better?

Comment: Yes, I would use the full name.  With IDE autocompletion you don't have to type the full names anyway.  If you keep evaluateRpn, you'd better make it evaluateRPN.

Comment: Yes, I did think quite a bit about that. You're right, it would be more elegant to use a grid, or define a row class. I ended up going with a 1D list since this was the format that the input (the expressions) and the output (the values) are in, so it seemed more natural.

Comment: @toto2: I would use the `evaluateReversePolishNotation()` but I think `evaluateRpn` is better than `evaluateRPN`. See *Effective Java, 2nd edition, Item 56: Adhere to generally accepted naming conventions*: "While uppercase may be more common, a strong argument can made in favor of capitalizing only the first letter: even if multiple acronyms occur back-to-back, you can still tell where one word starts and the next word ends. Which class name would you rather see, `HTTPURL` or `HttpUrl`?"

Answer (score 3):

Usually only a few cells of a spreadsheed are actually filled, so I'd suggest to use e.g. a `Map<Point, Cell>` to save memeory and to allow to use bigger spreadsheets.